# show/hide layers in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, show-hide, layer

First of all: I'm new to d3.js!

I have a map and some points displayed on it. Now I want to add buttons to show/hide the points. 
What I have until now:

```
function checkAll(){
    d3.selectAll("g").attr("visibility", "visible");
}
function uncheckAll(){
    d3.selectAll("g").attr("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

This works so far but hides/shows the whole map.

I have a function "drawpoints()" that draws the points on the map. 
How can I change my code that it only shows/hides the points and not the whole map?

Comment: Depends on what your "points" are. If they are circles, try `d3.selectAll("circle")...`.

Comment: they come from an geojson file and actually are only coordinates

Comment: What are the elements you're adding to represent the points?

Comment: you need to specify the elements that you want to hide/show in the selection, if the circles have all the same id or class you can do .selectAll("nameofcircles") and then apply the visibility property

Comment: They are all path elements. d3.selectAll("path")... works but all the parts I want to keep are also path elements. The circles have different classes and I also tried .selectAll("nameofcircles"), to see if it works for one group but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Say in a fiddle or something similar.

Comment: You would need to do `d3.selectAll(".classOfCircles")`.

Comment: Great, I'll post this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to select only the elements that you want to hide. If, for example, they are identified by a class, you would do the following:

```
d3.selectAll(".classOfCircles").attr("visibility", "hidden");
```