# Where to put .remove() to clear previous data points?

Tags: d3.js

I am having trouble updating my timeline after I switch time interval by zooming in or out. The old data points remain on my chart (timeline). I have tried adding .remove() after .filter() but it didn't work. Would appreciate any kind advice. Thanks.

```
    function update() {
        // re-position individual elements
        svg.selectAll('.element')
        //.remove()

        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval == 'hours') {
                return d.Interval == 'hour'; 
            }
            else if (interval == 'days') {
                return d.Interval == 'day'; 
            }
            else if (interval == 'weeks') {
                return d.Interval == 'week'; 
            }
            else if (interval == 'months') {
                return d.Interval == 'month'; 
            }
        })

        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            //return 'translate(' + xScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';

            if (interval == 'hours') {
                return 'translate(' + xHoursScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }
            if (interval == 'days') {
                return 'translate(' + xDaysScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }
            if (interval == 'weeks') {
                return 'translate(' + xWeeksScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }
            if (interval == 'months') {
                return 'translate(' + xMonthsScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }
        });
```

Comment: You're not binding any new data to your points, so no exit selection is computed. How do you determine which points to remove?

Comment: how do i bind data to a point? could you give me a simple example? thanks.

Comment: See e.g. [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Comment: is there a way to remove old data points without binding?

Comment: Well yes, you can select any element(s) and just call `.remove()` on them.

Comment: thanks lars. but when i did that svg.selectAll('.element').remove(), there isn't any data point on my timeline. where can i put it so that before the new elements get created, i can clear off the old ones?

Comment: This is what you would usually do with data binding. If you want to remove everything before adding new points, just call the code before you add the new ponts.

Comment: // create the elements based on the data provided
 var elem = svg.selectAll()
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'element')
  .attr('transform', function (d) {
   return 'translate(' + xScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
  });

Comment: I have added this at the top. Does that mean I can run elem.remove() to clear the old data points?

Comment: can i use filter() and remove() together?

Comment: You should be able to use `elem.exit().remove()`.

Comment: lars, thanks so much. you have been a great help. i found one of your older replies - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252174/show-hide-layers-in-d3-js - really helpful and have taken your suggestion there.

Comment: basically i implemented if...else... conditions to check if the time interval is hours/days/weeks/months, if not set the visibility to hidden. i understand that this will involve a lot of redundant codes but as i am in a rush to submit a prototype to my supervisor, it's my way out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval != 'hours') {
                return d.Interval == 'hour'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'hidden');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval != 'days') {
                return d.Interval == 'day'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'hidden');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval != 'weeks') {
                return d.Interval == 'week'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'hidden');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval != 'months') {
                return d.Interval == 'month'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'hidden');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval == 'hours') {
                return d.Interval == 'hour'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'visible');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval == 'days') {
                return d.Interval == 'day'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'visible');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval == 'weeks') {
                return d.Interval == 'week'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'visible');

        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .filter(function(d) { 
            if (interval == 'months') {
                return d.Interval == 'month'; 
            }
        })
        .attr('visibility', 'visible');
```